# google maps, fusion tables and markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-web-api

I have searched everywhere in the documentation to explain how I can show only markers for a given area of a fusion table.

At the moment all markers appear on the map like so:

[image]

[Fusion Table Google Maps](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3#rows:id=1)

[JSFiddle (note jsfiddle wont load the uri from website so markers wont show)](http://jsfiddle.net/wy03qpL5/28/)

If you click on an area of the fusion table/google map I get the area name in a pop up as expected, however I dont want to show any of the markers initially. When an area of the fusion table/map is clicked I want it to show the markers for that given area only, not the whole map.

This is how I add the markers to the map from my Web Api:

```
         var uri = 'http://mountainsandweather.azurewebsites.net/api/Mountains';

            $(document).ready(function () {
                //Get web api json data
                $.getJSON(uri)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        // On success, 'data' contains a list of mountains.
                        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                            // Add a list item for the mountain.
                            $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#mountains'));

                            //Put seperate data fields into one variable 
                            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);

                            //Add info window to each marker
                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: formatItemInfoWindow(item)
                            });


                            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latLng,
                                title: formatItemInfoWindow(item.Name),
                                infowindow: infowindow
                            });
                            marker.setMap(map);
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                //this.infowindow.close(); //not working correctly info windows still show
                                this.infowindow.open(map, marker);

                            });      
                        });
                    });
            });
            function formatItemInfoWindow(item) {
                return item.Name + '<br />' + item.Height_ft + '<br />' + item.humidity + '<br />' + item.snowCover + '<br />' + item.temperature;
            }
            function formatItem(item) {
                return item.Latitude +', '+ item.Longitude;
            }
        }
```

I did see in the documentation a `where` statement that can be added to the fusion tables. Like so:

```
 var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                    query: {
                        select: 'geometry',
                        from: '11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3'
                        where: //not sure if I could use this or what to put.
                    },
```

However the data from the Web Api is not segmented into specific areas it is simply one long list of Latitudes and Longitudes. Like so:

```
<Mountain>
<Height_ft>2999</Height_ft>
<Height_m>914</Height_m>
<ID>c1</ID>
<Latitude>57.588007</Latitude>
<Longitude>-5.5233564</Longitude>
<Name>Beinn Dearg</Name>
<humidity>0.81</humidity>
<snowCover>4.99</snowCover>
<temperature>63</temperature>
</Mountain>
```

Does google have anything in the way of mixing fusion table geometry with coordinates? A simple way of displaying all markers for a given area? Or can anyone think of a way this could be done?

Some extra details about the webapi incase it is needed:

```
    private MountainContext db = new MountainContext();

    // GET: api/Mountains
    public IQueryable<Mountain> GetMountains()
    {
        return db.Mountains;
    }

    // GET: api/Mountains/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Mountain))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMountain(string id)
    {
        Mountain mountain = db.Mountains.Find(id);
        if (mountain == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(mountain);
    }
    public IQueryable<Mountain> GetMountainByName(string name)
    {

        return db.Mountains.Where(n => string.Equals(n.Name, name));
    }
```

Comment: do you have the option to store the markers also in  the FusionTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no containsLocation function in FusionTablesLayer.

One solution is to create Google Maps Polygon from the FusionTablesLayer allowing us to use `containsLocation` to determine whether or not to add the marker to the map.

First we need the coordinates to create the polygon. We can use `google.visualization.Query` to grab the coordinates of the selected area from fusion table:

```
function getMountainPolygonFromFusionTable(label) {
    // Return a new promise.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var sql = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'geometry' FROM 11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3 WHERE label ='" + label + "'");
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + sql);

    query.send(function (response) {
        var data = response.getDataTable().getValue(0, 0);
        // Create a XML parser
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var kml = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
        } else { 
            var kml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            kml.loadXML(data);
        }

        // Get the coordinates of Mountain Areas
        var latLngs = kml.getElementsByTagName("coordinates")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.split(' ');

        var mountainPolygonLatLngs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < latLngs.length; i++) {
            var latLng = latLngs[i].split(',');
            mountainPolygonLatLngs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[1], latLng[0]));
        }

        // Create the polygon
        mountainPolygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: mountainPolygonLatLngs,
            fillColor: 'transparent',
            strokeColor : 'transparent'
        });

        resolve(mountainPolygons);

    });

  });
}
```

Then we just loop through the array of mountains and check to see if the selected area contains the mountain:

```
// On mountain area click
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(event) {

    // Clear all markers
    while(markers.length) { 
      markers.pop().setMap(null); 
    }

    // Get Polygon from FustionTable
    getMountainPolygonFromFusionTable(event.row.label.value).then(function(mountainPolygons) {

    // Loop through the mountains
    for(var i = 0; i < mountains.length; i++) {

        // Get the mountain LatLng
        var mountain = mountains[i];
        var mountainLat = mountain.getElementsByTagName("Latitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var mountainLng = mountain.getElementsByTagName("Longitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var mountainLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mountainLat, mountainLng);

        // If mountain is in the selected polygon, create a marker for it.
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(mountainLatLng, mountainPolygons)) {

            // @todo set infowindow, title...
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mountainLatLng,
                title: 'Marker info here',
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            markers.push(marker);

        }
    }

  });
});
```

Here's the JSON version:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(event) {

    // Clear all markers
    while(markers.length) { 
        markers.pop().setMap(null); 
    }

    // Get Polygone from FustionTable
    getMountainPolygonFromFusionTable(event.row.label.value).then(function(mountainPolygons) {

        $.getJSON(uri).done(function (data) {

            // On success, 'data' contains a list of mountains.
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {

                //Put seperate data fields into one variable 
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);

                if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latLng, mountainPolygons)) {

                    // @todo set infowindow, title...
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        title: 'Marker info here',
                    });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    markers.push(marker);

                }

            });

        });
    });
});
```

[Here's the Fiddle - XML](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/9wu90dze/3/)

[Here's the Fiddle - JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/9wu90dze/6/)

[And here's what the JSON API might look like](https://api.myjson.com/bins/4e50j)

Comment: @GarrithGraham, Ah, did wonder but the URL in your example points to an XML.. I've added a JSON version: http://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/9wu90dze/6/

Comment: @GarrithGraham Bizarre, The JSON used in the example follows the API docs: http://mountainsandweather.azurewebsites.net/Help/Api/GET-api-Mountains unless thats something different?. Have you a link to the API you are using?

Comment: That or your getMountainPolygonFromFusionTable function does not work with web api?

Comment: Looks like the jsapi library's missing for google.visualization.Query. 

Try adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` before our script and `google.load('visualization', '1.0');` just before `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);`

Comment: Hmm I dont have that script but the rest should be fine. I updated my question with the full code for the layout in my web api (MVC)

Comment: @GarrithGraham http://mountainsandweather.azurewebsites.net/ looks to be working now :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I am sure others will find this very helpful with both xml and json versions!

Comment: Hey Chris not sure if you could help on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685951/how-to-plot-polygon-data-from-csv-file-kml-fusion-table-workaround-for-android