# Extracting data from CSV file (fusion table and kml workaround)

Tags: c#, android, linq, google-maps, xamarin

In Xamarin google maps for Android using C# you can create polygons like so based on this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WU1WbkEviMM):

```
    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;
        PolylineOptions geometry = new PolylineOptions()
        .Add(new LatLng(37.35, -37.0123))
        .Add(new LatLng(37.35, -37.0123))
        .Add(new LatLng(37.35, -37.0123));


        Polyline polyline = mMap.AddPolyline(geometry);

    }
```

However I have downloaded a CSV file from my Fusion Table Layer from google maps as I think this might be the easiest option to work with polygon/polyline data. The output looks like this:

```
    description,name,label,geometry
    ,Highland,61,"<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-5.657018,57.3352 -5.656396,57.334463 -5.655076,57.334556 -5.653439,57.334477 -5.652366,57.334724 -5.650064,57.334477 -5.648096,57.335082 -5.646846,57.335388 -5.644733,57.335539 -5.643309,57.335428 -5.641981,57.335448 -5.640451,57.33578 -5.633217,57.339118 -5.627278,57.338921 -5.617161,57.337649 -5.607948,57.341015 -5.595812,57.343583 -5.586043,57.345373 -5.583581,57.350648 -5.576851,57.353609 -5.570088,57.354017 -5.560732,57.354102 -5.555254,57.354033 -5.549713,57.353146 -5.547766,57.352275 -5.538932,57.352255 -5.525891,57.356217 -5.514888,57.361865 -5.504272,57.366027 -5.494515,57.374515 -5.469829,57.383765 -5.458661,57.389781 -5.453695,57.395033 -5.454057,57.402943 -5.449189,57.40731 -5.440583,57.411447 -5.436133,57.414616 -5.438312,57.415474 -5.438628,57.417955 -5.440956,57.417909 -5.444013,57.414976 -5.450778,57.421362 -5.455035,57.422333 -5.462081,57.420719 -5.468775,57.416975 -5.475205,57.41135 -5.475976,57.409117 -5.47705,57.407092 -5.478101,57.406056 -5.478901,57.40536 -5.479489,57.404534 -5.480051,57.403782 -5.481036,57.403107 -5.484538,57.402102 -5.485647,57.401856 -5.487358,57.401287 -5.488709,57.400962 -5.490175,57.400616 -5.491116,57.400176 -5.493832,57.399318 -5.495279,57.399134 -5.496726,57.39771 -5.498724,57.396836 -5.49974,57.396314 -5.501317,57.39627 -5.502869,57.395426</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs></Polygon>"
    ,Strathclyde,63,"<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-5.603129,56.313564 -5.603163,56.312536 -5.603643,56.311794 -5.601467,56.311875 -5.601038,56.312481 -5.600697,56.313489 -5.60071,56.31535 -5.60159,56.316107 -5.600729,56.316598 -5.598625,56.316058 -5.596203,56.317477 -5.597024,56.318119 -5.596095,56.318739 -5.595432,56.320116 -5.589343,56.322469 -5.584888,56.325178 -5.582907,56.327169 -5.581414,56.327472 -5.581435,56.326663 -5.582355,56.325602 -5.581515,56.323891 -5.576993,56.331062 -5.57886,56.331475 -5.57676,56.334449 -5.572748,56.335689 -5.569012,56.338143 -5.564802,56.342113 -5.555237,56.346668 -5.551214,56.347448 -5.547651,56.346391 -5.54444,56.344945 -5.541247,56.345945 -5.539099,56.349674 -5.533874,56.34763 -5.525195,56.342888 -5.523518,56.345066 -5.52345,56.346605 -5.526417,56.354361 -5.535455,56.353681 -5.537463,56.35508 -5.536035,56.356271 -5.538923,56.357205 -5.53891,56.359336 -5.539952,56.361491 -5.538102,56.36372 -5.535934,56.36567 -5.53392,56.367705 -5.531369,56.369729 -5.529853,56.371022 -5.532371,56.371274 -5.534177,56.371708 -5.532846,56.373256 -5.529845,56.37496 -5.527675,56.375327 -5.528531,56.375995 -5.526732,56.376343 -5.525442,56.377809 -5.524739,56.379843 -5.526069,56.380561</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs></Polygon>"
```

I uploaded a KML file to `Google Maps Fusion Table Layer`, it then created the [map](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3#map:id=3). I then went `File>Download>CSV` and it gave me the above example.

I have added this csv file to my assets folder of my xamarin android google map app and my question would be because `LatLng` takes two doubles as its input, is there a way I could input the above data from the csv file into this method and if so how?

Not sure how to `read the above csv` and then extract the `<coordinates>` and then add those coordinates as new `LatLng` in the example code above?

If you notice however the coordinates are split into lat and lng and then the next `latlng` is seperated by a **space** `-5.657018,57.3352 -5.656396,57.334463`.

**Sudo code (this may or may not require xamarin or android experience and may just require C#/Linq)**:

```
Read CSV var sr = new StreamReader(Read csv from Asset folder);
Remove description,name,label,geometry
Foreach line in CSV
  Extract Item that contains double qoutes
     Foreach Item Remove Qoutes and <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates> from start and end
         Foreach item seperated by a space Extract coordinates
       (This will now leave a long list of 37.35,-37.0123 coordinates for each line)
        Place in something like this maybe?:

    public class Row
    {
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lng { get; set; }

        public Row(string str)
        {
            string[] separator = { "," };
            var arr = str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
            Lat = Convert.ToDouble(arr[0]);
            Lng = Convert.ToDouble(arr[1]);
        }
    }


    private void OnMapReady()
    var rows = new List<Row>();

      Foreach name/new line
         PolylineOptions geometry = new PolylineOptions()
           ForEach (item in rows) //not sure how polyline options will take a foreach
            .Add(New LatLng(item.Lat, item.Lng))
         Polyline polyline = mMap.AddPolyline(geometry);
```

As there is no way of using Fusion Table Layers in Xamarin Android with Google Maps API v2 this may provide a quick and easier workaround for those that need to split maps into regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to parse the above CSV file.

Each line (except the first one with headers) can be represented with the following class:

```
class MapEntry
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LatLng> InnerCoordinates { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LatLng> OuterCoordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `Inner` and `Outer` coordinates. They are represented inside the XML by `outerBoundaryIs` (required) and `innerBoundaryIs` (optional) elements.

A side note: the `Highland` line in your post is incorrect - you seem to trimmed part of the line, leading to incorrect XML (`<outerBoundaryIs>...</innerBoundaryIs>`).

Here is the code that does the parsing:

```
static IEnumerable<MapEntry> ParseMap(string csvFile)
{
    return from line in File.ReadLines(csvFile).Skip(1)
           let tokens = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, 4)
           let xmlToken = tokens[3]
           let xmlText = xmlToken.Substring(1, xmlToken.Length - 2)
           let xmlRoot = XElement.Parse(xmlText)
           select new MapEntry
           {
               Description = tokens[0],
               Name = tokens[1],
               Label = tokens[2],
               InnerCoordinates = GetCoordinates(xmlRoot.Element("innerBoundaryIs")),
               OuterCoordinates = GetCoordinates(xmlRoot.Element("outerBoundaryIs")),
           };
}

static IEnumerable<LatLng> GetCoordinates(XElement node)
{
    if (node == null) return Enumerable.Empty<LatLng>();
    var element = node.Element("LinearRing").Element("coordinates");
    return from token in element.Value.Split(' ')
           let values = token.Split(',')
           select new LatLng(XmlConvert.ToDouble(values[0]), XmlConvert.ToDouble(values[1]));
}
```

I think the code is self explanatory. The only details to be mentioned are:

```
let tokens = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, 4)
```

Here we use the `string.Split` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows us to *specify the maximum number of substrings to return*, thus avoiding the trap of processing the commas inside the XML token.

and:

```
let xmlText = xmlToken.Substring(1, xmlToken.Length - 2)
```

which strips the quotes from the XML token.

Finally, a sample usage for your case:

```
foreach (var entry in ParseMap(csv_file_full_path))
{
    PolylineOptions geometry = new PolylineOptions()
    foreach (var item in entry.OuterCoordinates)
        geometry.Add(item)
    Polyline polyline = mMap.AddPolyline(geometry);
}
```

**UPDATE:** To make Xamarin happy (as mentioned in the comments), replace the `File.ReadLines` call with a call to the following helper:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
{
    var sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open(path));
    try
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line; 
    }
    finally { sr.Dispose(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan +1 will try this soon.

Comment: @GarrithGraham Ok, then let fix that :)

Comment: I would remove the `File.` and do `return from ReadLines(csvFile).Skip(1)`

Comment: No diff at all. Just remove `static` if you need to access some state.

Comment: See update to question, looks like its not working. I had to change your sample usage however not sure thats the issue?

Comment: Hmm, I think the usage should be the way I posted it, the way you modified it you are adding all locations to single polyline, while the intent was to do that per each Name. What about the file format, that's not true - I've downloaded the file from the link exactly the way you described, and every `<outerBoundaryIs>` has a matching `</outerBoundaryIs>` tag **before** `<innerBoundaryIs>` and then `</innerBoundaryIs>` tag. You shouldn't be modifying manually the file and breaking the well formed XML.

Comment: Anyway, there is nothing more I can do. I can't test/debug the actual application, my goal was to get the parsing done, which I thing was met (after a few tweaks with your help), so my missing ends here.

Comment: It does, but there is closing tag inside the coordinates. Scroll at the end of the line and you'll see `</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs><innerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-5.662127,57.334252 -5.660896,57.336076 -5.662638,57.335369 -5.664319,57.334224 -5.662127,57.334252</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs></Polygon>"`

Comment: As I said, I can't test it. But since `item` is of type `LatLng`, `Add` method should compile (it's equivalent to your hard coded example). The only unknown is if the result of `Add` has to be assigned to the `geometry` variable.

Comment: I don't know if it's essential, but since the data is contained inside a XML `<Polygon>` tag, you could try using `PolygonOptions` and `AddPolygon` method - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/. But that's a blind guess.

Comment: Really? LOL, you are killing me. But seriously, I'm really glad that the issue is resolved.

Comment: Indeed. What can I say - same as yours!

Comment: Ivan got it working. Lat and Long where round the wrong way. This is now a workaround to the lack of Fusion Table Layers in the Android Google Maps API v2!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your questions but I think that can help:

You have to read the csv file line by line and foreach line extract the third argument, remove the quote and read the result with a XMLReader for extract the line you want (coordinate). After you split the result on white space, you get the list of LatLng and you split each LatLng on ",", then you've got all the information you need.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"file.csv");
string line = file.ReadLine(); //escape the first line
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var xmlString = line.Split({","})[2]; // or 3
    **Update**
    xmlString = xmlString.Replace("\"","")

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("coordinate");
        string coordinate = reader.Value;
        PolylineOptions geometry = new PolylineOptions();
        var latLngs = coordinate.Split({' '});
        foreach (var latLng in latLngs)
        {
            double lat = 0;
            double lng = 0;
            var arr = latLng.Split({','});
            double.TryParse(arr[0], out lat);
            double.TryParse(arr[1], out lng);
            geometry.Add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
        Polyline polyline = mMap.AddPolyline(geometry);
        // Do something with your polyline
    }
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: `System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. ` on this line  `reader.ReadToFollowing("coordinate");`

Comment: Exact, you have to remove the double quote in xmlString before passing it to the XmlReader with xmlString.Replace("\"","")

Comment: The code you have in your answer does not compile. I have also attempted work arounds with no success still get the same issue on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication35
{
    public class LatLng
    {
        public LatLng(double lat, double lng)
        {
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<LatLng> GetCoordinates(string polygon)
        {
            var xElement = XElement.Parse(polygon);
            //var innerBoundaryCoordinates = xElement.Elements("innerBoundaryIs").FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? "";
            var outerBoundaryCoordinates = xElement.Elements("outerBoundaryIs").Single()?.Value ?? "";
            return outerBoundaryCoordinates
                .Split(' ')
                .Select(latLng =>
                {
                    var splits = latLng.Split(',');
                    var lat = double.Parse(splits[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    var lng = double.Parse(splits[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return new LatLng(lat, lng);
                });
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            const string header = "description,name,label,geometry";
            var latLngs = File.ReadLines("file.csv")
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Split(new[] { header }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) //all geometry`s in one array
                              .Select(x => x.Split('"'))
                              .SelectMany(x => GetCoordinates(x[1]))
                              .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See updated question. Your method crashes the app with no error output at all? Seems to be happening on this line: `.SelectMany(x => GetCoordinates(x[1]))`

Comment: Taking away GetCoordinates `.SelectMany(x => (x[1]))` and outputing the array to a console window shows a new line for every individual character. Is this what you where expecting as an input for `string polygon`

Comment: Ok) I download original resource from your [map](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3#map:id=3) link. Code works fine. `GetCoordinates(x[1])` is safe operation for this file format.

Comment: I use simple C# console.application. It is just example how you may parse file. For example you may use this utility and convert your csv file into other format for your android app. Try run this tool with this file [map](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3#map:id=3) and then debug & rewrite it for android.

Comment: Your example with StreamReader is equivalent and it works too. I suppose that your file `regions.csv` is different than [map](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=11RJmSNdTr7uC867rr2zyzNQ6AiE1hcREmGFTlvH3#map:id=3)

Comment: The only thing I changed from that data was the name of the file. I will download and test it again later. Have you tried this in Xamarin? Its a free to install and use. The only other thing I can think of is when resolving the required namespaces I have used some android variant of `XElement, StreamReader or Linq`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120242/discussion-between-dmitryzyr-and-garrith-graham).

Comment: Ok I used a console app and could not get the output of the array to work.